# isSemiBalanced() Java BST method not passing test

Tags: java, scala, recursion, intellij-idea, binary-search-tree

I'm using Intellij IDEA and am testing my BST to see if it is semi-balanced. Semi-balanced (at least as this project specifies) means that every node in the tree is semi-balanced:

A node with 0 children is semi-perfect.

A node with 1 child is NOT semi-perfect.

A node with 2 children is semi-perfect if (size-of-larger-child <= size-of-smaller-child * 3)

I've implemented the following code in eclipse. It passes every BST I've thrown at it but it will not pass this test in Intellij IDEA. I've included my method below (that works in Eclipse when ran through the main() function) and also the test that my method must pass in IDEA (which it does not, and is currently my problem). The test is written in Scala. Thanks guys.

```
  //My Java method and helper method
  public static boolean isSemiBalanced (Node t) {
    int n = isSemiBalancedInt(t);
    if (n <= -1) return false;
    return true;
  }

  private static int isSemiBalancedInt(Node node) {
    if (node == null) return 1;
    if (node.left == null && node.right == null) return 0;
    else if (node.left == null || node.right == null) return -1;
    else {
      int sizeMax = Math.max(isSemiBalancedInt(node.left), isSemiBalancedInt(node.right));
      int sizeMin = Math.min(isSemiBalancedInt(node.left), isSemiBalancedInt(node.right));
      if (sizeMax == -1 || sizeMin == -1) return -1;
      if (sizeMax <= 3 * sizeMin) return isSemiBalancedInt(node.left) + isSemiBalancedInt(node.right);
    }
    return -1;
  }


//Scala code that checks my Java method
import org.scalatest._
import org.scalacheck.Gen

class hw1tests extends UnitSpec {
  val EX : Map[Int, Tag] = 
    (for (i <- (1 to 12).toList) yield {
      object T extends Tag ("hw1ex%02d".format (i))
      (i, T)
    }).toMap

  import hw1._
  import hw1.NodeSamples._
  import stdlib._

  val trees : List[Node] = List (t01, t02, t03, t04, t05, t06, t07, t08, t09, t10)
  val treesCopy : List[Node] = for (t <- trees) yield NodeOps.copy (t)

  def compareToDepth (t1 : Node, t2 : Node, k : Int) : Boolean = {
    if (k < 0) {
      true
    } else if ((t1 eq null) || (t2 eq null)) {
      t1 eq t2
    } else {
      (t1.key == t2.key) && compareToDepth (t1.left, t2.left, k - 1) && compareToDepth (t1.right, t2.right, k - 1)
    }
  }

  def traversal (t : Node) : List[Int] = {
    if (t eq null) {
      Nil
    } else {
      traversal (t.left) ++ List (t.key) ++ traversal (t.right)
    }
  }

  def noChange () = {
    for ((t1, t2) <- trees.zip (treesCopy)) {
      assert (compareToDepth (t1, t2, 10) === true)
    }
  }

  property ("EX09 - isSemiBalancedTest", EX (9)) {
    val sizeTable = Table (
      ("t", "isSemiBalanced (t)"),
      (t01,  true),
      (t02, false),
      (t03, false),
      (t04,  true),
      (t05,  true),
      (t06, false),
      (t07,  true),
      (t08,  true),
      (t09,  true),
      (t10,  true)
    )
    forAll (sizeTable) { (t : Node, res : Boolean) =>
      assert (NodeOps.isSemiBalanced (t) ===  res)
    }
    noChange
  }
```

Comment: What is the error message you get for the failing test? You shouldn't have to do this: `assert( === )` since `===` is an assert itself

Comment: I cannot mess with the Scala - That's what the Java is run against. Here's the message:

Comment: - EX09 - isSemiBalancedTest *** FAILED ***
[info]   TestFailedException was thrown during property evaluation. (hw1tests.scala:223)
[info]     Message: false did not equal true
[info]     Location: (hw1tests.scala:224)
[info]     Occurred at table row 0 (zero based, not counting headings), which had values (
[info]       t = hw1.Node@2e4d892d,
[info]       isSemiBalanced (t) = true
[info]     )

Comment: Do you run tests in the same way in both IDEs (as JUnit, or some other way)? Check the test launcher classpath and JVM args - compare. For each test IDE usually prints some run details. See what it prints in Intellij. What is your build based on. Is it Maven, SBT? Run tests from there and check results. I suspect that test runners are different and/or have different settings

Comment: I already have, the test file actually has 13 different tests - all of which work except for this isSemiBalanced one. I guess a better question is, is my code solid given the parameters I listed in the question? i.e., is it my code or the test that is the problem. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe create a much simpler test which has to fail with the property as in your error message. Just a single check would be enough, then compare behavior in different IDEs.

Comment: Yeah worth a shot, will do thanks. Problem is that this test has to pass so even if it's an IDE issue and it passes, the requirement is still that it passes on IntelliJ and with this exact Scala doc. Either way it's worth a shot so thanks again.